# Ubuntu Oracle Instant Client tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames, oracleclient

I had recently set up Oracle Instant Client on Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to connect to a database located on a different server through sqlplus with the command:

```
sqlplus username@orcl
```

I had edited my tnsnames.ora file in the following format:

```
ORCL= 
 (DESCRIPTION= 
   (ADDRESS=(hostname)(PORT=1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA= 
     (SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

And after I put in the password it get the error message:

```
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

If I were to manually type in the connection data such as

```
sqlplus username/password@orcl:portnumber/service_name
```

I would be about to connect, but I wish to not type all of the connection data and leave it to just username@host

I am not sure what is causing the error and don't know if I need to edit any files on the server side where the actual database is hosted to allow for such a connection. Thank you

Comment: You missed the port, see valid example at https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora

Comment: Also maybe this is obvious, but in your example you're using `ORCL=` so your command should be `sqlplus username@ORCL`

Comment: Sorry, just updated my question. I do use a port and have been trying to connect to the actual database name. I just used vague keywords when presenting the example in the question. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If it fails like described the service_name for the entry in the tnsnames.ora file is wrong.

I would make a copy of the tnsnames.ora file to a folder and rename the entry from ORCL to something unique for my test

> oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ mkdir tst oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ cp
>   product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora tst/
>   oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ vim tst/tnsnames.ora  oracle@befb83f389c6:~$
>   cat tst/tnsnames.ora
>
> ## tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:
>
> ONLYFORME =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = befb83f389c6)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
>       )   )
>
> EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = PLSExtProc)
>         (PRESENTATION = RO)
>       )   )
>
> at this point tnsping to the name ONLYFORME will fail as the client does not know about the copy of the tnsnames.ora file
>
> oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ tnsping ONLYFORME
>
> TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on
>   06-OCT-2018 12:18:51
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>
> TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

to compensate we set the TNS_ADMIN env varaiable

> oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ export TNS_ADMIN=/u01/app/oracle/tst/
>   oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ tnsping ONLYFORME
>
> TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on
>   06-OCT-2018 12:19:16
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>
> Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias Attempting to contact
>   (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = befb83f389c6)(PORT =
>   1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE))) OK
>   (0 msec) oracle@befb83f389c6:~$

now tnsping to ONLYFORME works

connecting with sqlplus using this name also works fine

> oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ sqlplus iasim@ONLYFORME
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Oct 6 12:22:43 2018
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Enter password:
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 -
>   64bit Production
>
> SQL>

to reproduce the error youre getting we might put in an unknown service name

> oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ cat tst/tnsnames.ora
>
> ## tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:
>
> ONLYFORME =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = befb83f389c6)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = UNKNOWN_XE)
>       )   )
>
> EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = PLSExtProc)
>         (PRESENTATION = RO)
>       )   )
>
> oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ sqlplus iasim@ONLYFORME
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Oct 6 12:25:17 2018
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Enter password:  ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently
>   know of service requested in connect descriptor
>
> Enter user-name:

at this point we know which tnsnames.ora file it is that resolves the tnsname we're using (ONLYFORME) and we know where the error is

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you don't want to type password;

this method is usually done by dba's who logs as ssh user into that particular server/host directly, wherein their password is stored as hashed-private/public-keys
(Not from remote machines)

the simpler way is to use like sqlplus username/password@remote_host_ip:1521/orcl
better yet create alias in your kshrc/bashrc file ( and source them ) for the above so you get what you need with fewer keystrokes.

eg:
nano .bashrc
alias tosql='sqlplus username/password@remote_host_ip:1521/orcl'